# How do I inject an Application in a Transfuse Singleton

Tags: android, transfuse

How can I create a singleton that gets injected with an application context. Just annotating with @Singleton and then using @Inject on the constructor ends up generating an UnscopedProvider class that will not compile. How can I make an ApplicationScoped provider... or is there another mechanism to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ended on here is to create an `init(Application app) {}` method on the Singleton, then inject the Singleton into my `@Application` annotated class and call the init method using the Application that's injected into that class. I think this is the only way to do this currently.

Comment: This is a good approach and arguably better than injecting the Application.  However, this is currently a workaround of this bug: https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/issues/62